# How to confirm which version of the FB API my Android App is hitting?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on finishing up an Android app that has been under development for ages. The app uses the Facebook SDK for Android to post a simple link to the users wall after making a selection from a PlacePicker fragment. The SDK was very old and was using v1.0 of the FB API, so I have had to update it before we publish. The SDK update - while frustrating - was successful and the app still works without any further changes.
There is also a Rails application which uses the same FB App for Omniauth registration/login. The Rails app uses the `omniauth-facebook` gem, which has been updated. There were no further updates needed for the Rails app either.

The client, however, is requesting "proof" that the app now uses >=v2.0 of the FB API and I am not sure what to give them. FB is clearly capable of knowing when a FB App is receiving outdated API calls, but can it show me whether it's receiving >=v2.0 API calls? So far the only thing I have been able to find is an Insights graph of daily API call counts but there is no information about the calls other than their quantity.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this dashboard to see if your app is showing in the "Top Affected Apps" table. If so, it will tell you what percent of the calls is v2.x.

Also if you can debug the app, put a breakpoint here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Request.java#L233

Or call the `getVersion()` method on your request object to see what version it's hitting.